# Django 1.6: Forgot password not sending email

Tags: python, django, email

I'm trying to implement django's built-in forgot password, but I never receive the email. I've checked my spam folder and still nothing. It shows me the password reset sucessful page after typing in the email but I never get the email.

settings.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'something@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'something'

DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'something@gmail.com'
SERVER_EMAIL = 'something@gmail.com'
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^forgot-password/$', views.forgot_password, name="forgot-password"),
```

views.py

```
def forgot_password(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return password_reset(request, 
            from_email=request.POST.get('email'))
    else:
        return render(request, 'meddy1/forgot_password.html')
```

I've tried testing it in the python manage.py shell by doing the following

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
email = EmailMessage('Subject', 'Message', to=['something@gmail.com'])
email.send()
```

It gives me the output of 1 but i still don't get any email!!

I then tried this python manage.py shell by doing the following

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
send_mail('Subject here', 'Here is the message.', 'something@gmail.com',
    ['somethingelse@gmail.com'], fail_silently=False)
```

It gives me the output of 1 and I **successfully receive** the email in my inbox.

I have no idea why it's not sending the email through the form.

Comment: Did you try an alternate server?

Comment: @AshishKasturia What do you mean alternate server? Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: Alternate email server.

Comment: @HarisB. the fact that your message is sent doesn't garantee it will be delivered. Try another SMTP server (possibly a local one - sendmail or like) and see what happens. FWIW we have quite a couple sites on production running Django 1.6 and older versions and I can tell you that `email.send()` does work.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I tried send_mail in python manage.py shell and I successfully get the email. What does that mean?

Comment: It means that gmail is rejecting your email. As I mentioned earlier, try a different email server, like hotmail or yahoo and see if you get the same result. If so, then there is something wrong with your code. If the email gets delivered, try posting your query on google's help pages.

Comment: @AshishKasturia I don't understand how gmail is rejecting the email ? I tried importing send_mail instead of EmailMessage(I've updated the answer) and used the same gmail setting configuration and I successfully received the email.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why I was not getting the email was because I was storing the user's email address as the username on signup. Because I wanted to authenticate using email address instead of username. So whenever I entered the email address in the forgot password page it would redirect me to the page saying the email has been sent. But I'd never get any email because **it never found the email in the database**. Ideally, It should actually raise an error saying email address not found. But it doesn't!!!

I need to find a way to do that.

So currently I'm saving the user's email address as username and email address. I know it's not a good idea to do that because of data redundancy. But it works!